# Show a modal UI in the middle of background operation and continue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I have a WPF application running a background task which uses `async/await`. The task is updating the app's status UI as it progresses. During the process, if a certain condition has been met, I am required to show a modal window to make the user aware of such event, and then continue processing, now also updating the status UI of that modal window.

This is a sketch version of what I am trying to achieve:

```
async Task AsyncWork(int n, CancellationToken token)
{
    // prepare the modal UI window
    var modalUI = new Window();
    modalUI.Width = 300; modalUI.Height = 200;
    modalUI.Content = new TextBox();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // main loop
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // do the next step of async process
            var data = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.bing.com/search?q=item" + i);

            // update the main window status
            var info = "#" + i + ", size: " + data.Length + Environment.NewLine;
            ((TextBox)this.Content).AppendText(info); 

            // show the modal UI if the data size is more than 42000 bytes (for example)
            if (data.Length < 42000)
            {
                if (!modalUI.IsVisible)
                {
                    // show the modal UI window 
                    modalUI.ShowDialog();
                    // I want to continue while the modal UI is still visible
                }
            }

            // update modal window status, if visible
            if (modalUI.IsVisible)
                ((TextBox)modalUI.Content).AppendText(info);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with `modalUI.ShowDialog()` is that it is a blocking call, so the processing stops until the dialog is closed. It would not be a problem if the window was modeless, but it has to be modal, as dictated by the project requirements.

Is there a way to get around this with `async/await`?

Comment: Use modalUI.Show() method and try to set IsHitTestVisible to false(it prevent events firing on mainwindow) for MainWindow and change the opactiy(if need)..

Comment: @Ravuthasamy, I actually want it to behave like (and be!) a normal modal window. I think the main problem is that it runs on its own message loop.

Comment: Is this essentially an overlay over part of the screen that stops the user for interacting with part or all of the UI?

Comment: @JamieClayton, yes, essentially that's what it is, besides I also like the user to be able to interact with the modal dialog UI, while the main UI stays blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by executing `modalUI.ShowDialog()` asynchronously (upon a future iteration of the UI thread's message loop). The following implementation of `ShowDialogAsync` does that by using `TaskCompletionSource` ([EAP task pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/19/9791857.aspx)) and `SynchronizationContext.Post`.

Such execution workflow might be a bit tricky to understand, because your asynchronous task is now spread across two separate WPF message loops: the main thread's one and the new nested one (started by `ShowDialog`). IMO, that's perfectly fine, we're just taking advantage of the `async/await` state machine provided by C# compiler.

Although, when your task comes to the end while the modal window is still open, you probably want to wait for user to close it. That's what `CloseDialogAsync` does below. Also, you probably should account for the case when user closes the dialog in the middle of the task (AFAIK, a WPF window can't be reused for multiple `ShowDialog` calls).

The following code works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfAsyncApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Content = new TextBox();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        // AsyncWork
        async Task AsyncWork(int n, CancellationToken token)
        {
            // prepare the modal UI window
            var modalUI = new Window();
            modalUI.Width = 300; modalUI.Height = 200;
            modalUI.Content = new TextBox();

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // main loop
                    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                        // do the next step of async process
                        var data = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.bing.com/search?q=item" + i);

                        // update the main window status
                        var info = "#" + i + ", size: " + data.Length + Environment.NewLine;
                        ((TextBox)this.Content).AppendText(info);

                        // show the modal UI if the data size is more than 42000 bytes (for example)
                        if (data.Length < 42000)
                        {
                            if (!modalUI.IsVisible)
                            {
                                // show the modal UI window asynchronously
                                await ShowDialogAsync(modalUI, token);
                                // continue while the modal UI is still visible
                            }
                        }

                        // update modal window status, if visible
                        if (modalUI.IsVisible)
                            ((TextBox)modalUI.Content).AppendText(info);
                    }
                }

                // wait for the user to close the dialog (if open)
                if (modalUI.IsVisible)
                    await CloseDialogAsync(modalUI, token);
            }
            finally
            {
                // always close the window
                modalUI.Close();
            }
        }

        // show a modal dialog asynchronously
        static async Task ShowDialogAsync(Window window, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            using (token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled(), useSynchronizationContext: true))
            {
                RoutedEventHandler loadedHandler = (s, e) =>
                    tcs.TrySetResult(true);

                window.Loaded += loadedHandler;
                try
                {
                    // show the dialog asynchronously 
                    // (presumably on the next iteration of the message loop)
                    SynchronizationContext.Current.Post((_) => 
                        window.ShowDialog(), null);
                    await tcs.Task;
                    Debug.Print("after await tcs.Task");
                }
                finally
                {
                    window.Loaded -= loadedHandler;
                }
            }
        }

        // async wait for a dialog to get closed
        static async Task CloseDialogAsync(Window window, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            using (token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled(), useSynchronizationContext: true))
            {
                EventHandler closedHandler = (s, e) =>
                    tcs.TrySetResult(true);

                window.Closed += closedHandler;
                try
                {
                    await tcs.Task;
                }
                finally
                {
                    window.Closed -= closedHandler;
                }
            }
        }

        // main window load event handler
        async void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(30000);
            try
            {
                // test AsyncWork
                await AsyncWork(10, cts.Token);
                MessageBox.Show("Success!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[EDITED]** Below is a slightly different approach which uses `Task.Factory.StartNew` to invoke `modalUI.ShowDialog()` asynchronously. The returned `Task` can be awaited later to make sure the user has closed the modal dialog.

```
async Task AsyncWork(int n, CancellationToken token)
{
    // prepare the modal UI window
    var modalUI = new Window();
    modalUI.Width = 300; modalUI.Height = 200;
    modalUI.Content = new TextBox();

    Task modalUITask = null;

    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // main loop
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                // do the next step of async process
                var data = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.bing.com/search?q=item" + i);

                // update the main window status
                var info = "#" + i + ", size: " + data.Length + Environment.NewLine;
                ((TextBox)this.Content).AppendText(info);

                // show the modal UI if the data size is more than 42000 bytes (for example)
                if (data.Length < 42000)
                {
                    if (modalUITask == null)
                    {
                        // invoke modalUI.ShowDialog() asynchronously
                        modalUITask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                            () => modalUI.ShowDialog(),
                            token,
                            TaskCreationOptions.None,
                            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

                        // continue after modalUI.Loaded event 
                        var modalUIReadyTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                        using (token.Register(() => 
                            modalUIReadyTcs.TrySetCanceled(), useSynchronizationContext: true))
                        {
                            modalUI.Loaded += (s, e) =>
                                modalUIReadyTcs.TrySetResult(true);
                            await modalUIReadyTcs.Task;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // update modal window status, if visible
                if (modalUI.IsVisible)
                    ((TextBox)modalUI.Content).AppendText(info);
            }
        }

        // wait for the user to close the dialog (if open)
        if (modalUITask != null)
            await modalUITask;
    }
    finally
    {
        // always close the window
        modalUI.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do what I am looking for. I feel like I need to step through it in the debugger to understand it better.

Comment: @avo, on a side note, you can use `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` instead of `SynchronizationContext.Post`.

Comment: I wonder why ShowDialogAsync was not added in .NET 4.5. It really should have been.