# Long running task with dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

I have this long running process and I want to display a form over the main app form explaining that it is long running with the ubiquitous circle progress bar. I just can't get anything to work properly. The form doesn't show properly or animate the progress circle. If I try a different method as shown then the task doesn't finish!

```
private void lbMethods_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (lbMethods.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case (int)Methods.none:
                break;
            case (int)Methods.Susan:
                Log("Starting Susan Edge Detection");
                Progressing("Please wait for edge detection");
                Task t = new Task(() => ProcessSusan());
                while (!t.IsCompleted)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
                Log("Detection Finished");
                Progressing("", false);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ProcessSusan()
    {
        Susan s = new Susan(CurrentImage);
        List<IntPoint> corners = s.GetCorners();
    }

    private void Progressing(string message, bool Show = true)
    {

        if (Show)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = message;
            Progress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "...";
            Progress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
        }
    }
```

The long running form code looks like this:

```
public partial class FrmProcessing : Form
{
    public string description { get; set; }

    public FrmProcessing(string description)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblDescription.Text = description;

    }

    // Let the calling method close this form.
    public void Close()
    {

        this.Close();
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's any point to doing this?  If something takes a long time *consistently* then there's no point in entertaining the user with a "it takes a long time" spinner.  They get the message after a few times, just stop looking at it and fire up Solitaire.  Accommodate that with, say, a NotifyIcon.  Or just make sure that they *never* feel like they have to wait for it, that's just awful.

Comment: where do you create FrmProcessing?

Comment: @Hans.. thats an awful suggestion. That requires the user be "trained" to know that the application hasn't locked up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Application.DoEvents()` is often misused. On top of the common issue with the code re-entrancy via UI, you're also executing a [busy-waiting loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).

You didn't specify where exactly you want to display the modal dialog. As I understand it, the code might look like this:

```
private void lbMethods_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (lbMethods.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case (int)Methods.none:
            break;
        case (int)Methods.Susan:
            Log("Starting Susan Edge Detection");
            Progressing("Please wait for edge detection");

            var dialog = new FrmProcessing();
            dialog.StartTaskFunc = () =>
                Task.Run(ProcessSusan);
            dialog.ShowDialog();

            Log("Detection Finished");
            Progressing("", false);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public partial class FrmProcessing : Form
{
    public Func<Task> StartTaskFunc { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }

    public FrmProcessing(string description)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblDescription.Text = description;

        // async event handler for "Form.Load"
        this.Load += async (s, e) =>
        {
            // start the task and await it
            await StartTaskFunc();
            // close the modal form when the task finished
            this.Close();
        };
    }
}
```

This is just a skeletal implementation. You should add some exception handling, cancellation and progress report logic for `ProcessSusan`. Here is a very good read on how to do that: [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx).

I've also answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20917996/1768303) recently. See if you can use the same approach.

Comment: When implementing this, the task begins but the GUI does not load/show.

Comment: @AdamReed, feel free to post a minimal self-contained code repro'ing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are not taking advantage of what `TPL` actually offers.

The following code snippet still blocks the GUI thread:

```
Task t = new Task(() => ProcessSusan());
while (!t.IsCompleted)
{
  Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Because it will cycle so rapidly, the results will be undesirable.  Replace it with the following:

```
await Task.Run(()=>ProcessSusan());
```

This will put the process on a different thread, and then invoke the second half of your method on the GUI thread once `ProcessSusan()` completes.

**NOTE**

You must be the `async` keyword after `private` in the method definition.

Comment: This doesn't address the case when `lbMethods_SelectedIndexChanged` is fired while `await Task.Run(()=>ProcessSusan())` hasn't finished yet. The OP most certainly doesn't want **multiple `ProcessSusan` running in parallel.** It also doesn't answer how to display the modal form.

Comment: @Noseratio, actually it does to a certain extent. The previous code does not return control of the UI thread to the user. The user would not be able to have multiple `ProcessSusan`s running in parallel at all. The first step is to push the work onto another thread. Which Andrew suggested. The next step is to create a `TaskCancelationToken` to pass into the `Task.Run`, so that the UI thread can kill the existing run.

Comment: @Aron, that's why I didn't down-vote this answer. However, it is not what the OP asks for, is it: *I want to display a form over the main app form explaining that it is long running with the ubiquitous circle progress bar.*