# How to show content dialog from background task in uwp app

Tags: windows, dialog, uwp, background-process

I'm trying to develop an application which runs background task ( reading rfid sensor of a machine ) I want to create another task  for reporting machine state it will check last time sensor is read and when its more than 5 min it will prompt user to choose the reason of waiting. After it shows I want task to continue checking because if machine starts working  before user choose something from content dialog I want to hide content dialog and continue to working. Of course I'm not asking for full code :) It would be great if you can give very short example of a background task which can display content dialog and continue to run. Closest example I found is this but I could not understand and implement to my code [Show a modal UI in the middle of background operation and continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917996/show-a-modal-ui-in-the-middle-of-background-operation-and-continue)

Thank you very much.

```
 await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
              () =>
              {
                  if (DialogisOpen == false)
                  {
                      //its been 3 min since machine is not working so we      are showing user dialog to ask for a reason 
                      mp = new MainPage();
                      mp.TestUi();
                      DialogisOpen = true;

                  }

              });
```

Comment: you can't... but you can get users attention with a toast notification.

Comment: thank you for answer. But are you sure ? this link i shared this guy seems he made

Comment: It's WPF he is taking about and you do UWP. A background task in UWP can't show any UI because the foreground app is not running. Only work with toast notification for example. WPF on the other hand is not having the background task system as UWP.  Are you sure you are using a background task?

Comment: Yes i know thats why i asked uwp version of this.Actually i just did what i wanted but im now sure its correct way to do it so im open for alternatives. i cannot paste my code here its too long i will edit my question with my current code part

Answer (score 1):

A BackgroundTask doesn't have any UI support so can't show any UI (including a ContentDialog) because it doesn't have any access to the UI Thread but there are a few things you could do instead.

- Have the BG Task display a ToastNotification (which does have UI)
- Don't use a background task, have a full app that runs minimized and a separate process to keep this running.
- Do it in WPF where your example works. (You haven't said if there's a reason you can't do this.)
- Have your BGTask send a message (in any of various ways) to (or launch) another process on the machine that can display the prompt.